# Not in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, replace, string-matching, regex-greedy

I am trying to write a regex pattern for finding a spesific string which is not inside of quotation marks. for example;

```
where value = '~foo'; //no match

where value = ~foo; //match
```

I may seek until finding the spesific string like;

> ^(?:(?!~).)*

but that is not really helped me. If I may define the literal string "not in" statement that may solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookarounds like this

```
(?<!')yourWordGoesHere(?!')
```

Comment: shouldn't that be a negative? (?<!')yourWordGoesHere(?!')

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
~foo(?!(.(?<!'))*?')
```

Result:

[image: Not in quotes]

Comment: This just tests if there's a quote at the end.

Comment: @TimRogers in what cases this won't work? seem pretty working to me.

Comment: It will match `~foo'` but not `'~foo`. Depends if that's acceptable or not.

Comment: The pattern at the end is kind of a mess, not sure why you are using a look-behind in there.  You could just use `(?!.*')`.

Comment: I realise it isn't the most efficient. When I am back at my desk I will fix it up.